# Stopping sticky sidebar at footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get it so the last div on my sidebar stays sticky when the page scrolls, but stops at the footer. How to calculate the limit? Here is my code:

```js
var stickyTop = $('#aside1').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var limit = $('footer').offset().top - $('#aside1').height();

  if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
    $('#aside1').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '150px' });
  } else {
    $('#aside1').css('position','static');
  }

  if (limit < windowTop) {
    var diff = limit - windowTop;
    $('#aside1').css({top: diff});
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #aba;
}
header, main, footer {
  display: block;
  max-width: 740px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 200%;
  background: #456;
  text-align: center;
}
header a {
  color: #fff;
}
article {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 485px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #fff;
}
aside {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #cff inset;
  background: #cdc;
}
footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  clear: both;
  height: 800px;
  background: #456;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  Sticky sidebar
</header>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<main>
  <article id="article"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi maiores repellat et, asperiores tempore! Provident velit illo, in quod ea explicabo, dignissimos dolorem voluptatibus, quisquam voluptas consectetur fugiat vel?</h1></article>
  <aside id="aside1">1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20</aside>
</main>

<footer></footer>
```

Sandbox: http://jsbin.com/yivomexixi/edit?html,output